# Equation of Sun Orbit Spiral on Azimuthal Equidistant Earth Map

Tags: analysis, reference-request, word-problem

From the perspective of the AE map:
The sun circles the earth. Every complete circle it makes is approximately one day. However, the sun is not always on the circle of the equator. It spirals inward from the equator to the tropic of cancer, and outward from the equator to the tropic of capricorn.

Let's assume the year starts at the spring equinox (about March 20th). At that point the sun is circling the equator. Around 3 months later (summer solstice) the sun has spiraled inward and is now at the tropic of cancer. Around 3 months later again (fall equinox) the sun has spiraled outward and is back at the equator. Around 3 months later (winter solstice) the sun has spiraled outward further and is at the tropic of capricorn. Around 3 months later (back at spring equinox again) the sun has spiraled inward and returned to the equator again. The year is complete.

**My question is, how does one find the equation of the spiral of the sun for the AE map?** If this equation is found, you could calculate the exact position of the sun at any given point of time on the AE map (which is ultimately the goal).

[AE MAP: Visual aid for help understanding explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2bCk.png)

[Hand-done speculation of what spiral would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMQnJ.jpg)

Comment: Are you assuming simple mean Keplerian elements?

Comment: My assumptions are based on some numbers. I'm not necessarily looking for this to be scientifically accurate. Let's say there are 12 months in a year, and exactly 30 days in each month. And let's say the 4 equinoxes/solstice days are added outside of that year, but are of course a part of the sun's cycle. So ultimately the solar year would in this model would be 364 days. between the spring equinox and the summer solstice, the sun has to spiral around 90 days/times. Between the summer solstice and the fall equinox, the sun has to spiral around 90 days, and so forth, until the year is complete.

Comment: Ahh, so you are willing to approximate the situation with a circular orbit that's just inclined by 23.5 degrees or so?

Comment: @BrianTung If that works. From my research, some months have the sun between the tropics/equator. I made an amateur layout of what I thought the orbit might look like. But it's only based on estimations. Check out the new photo I added to my post. the "M1-12" are the month numbers if you start at the spring equinox